# Flutter Stateful widget does not rebuild

Tags: flutter, dart

thanks for your help in advance, I have an application that is basically a TODO app, the problem here is that I have a List of type String in which the user will put the tasks that he needs to do, and that is why what I try to do is to check when the list is still empty, show a Column with an image, and if the user adds an item the list is no longer empty, so it shows the list and not the column, for that I have made a simple if in the method `buildscreen()` .
The problem: The widget after adding a new item to my list is not rebuilt again even after calling a setState in `addTask()` and therefore it does not see if the list is full or empty and it continues to show the Column with the image.

Here is the code

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:todo_app/custom_icons_icons.dart';

class Todo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TodoState createState() => _TodoState();
}

List<String> tasks = [];
var hour= DateTime.now().hour;
int listlength= tasks.length;



class _TodoState extends State<Todo> {
  GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> globalKey= new GlobalKey<AnimatedListState>();
  void addTask(String text){
    print("Add task is built");
    setState(() {
      tasks.insert(0,text);
      globalKey.currentState.insertItem(0);


    });



  }

  void removeTask(int index){
setState(() {
  globalKey.currentState.removeItem(index, (context,animation){
    return SizedBox(width: 0, height: 0);

  });
  tasks.removeAt(index);

});
  }

  Widget promptRemove(int index){
    showDialog(context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext builder){
     return AlertDialog(
       title: Text("Do you want to mark ${tasks[index]} as done?"),
       actions: [
          FlatButton(onPressed:() {
            removeTask(index);
            Navigator.pop(context);
          }
              , child: Text("Mark as Done")),
         FlatButton(onPressed:(){
           Navigator.pop(context);
         }, child: Text("Cancel"))

       ],
      );
    }
    );
  }

  Widget buildItem(String text, int index){
    return Dismissible(
      key: Key("${text.hashCode}"),
      onDismissed: (direction)=> removeTask(index),
      direction: DismissDirection.startToEnd,
      child: Card(
        elevation: 4,
        child: ListTile(
          leading: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 5
              ),
              child: Container(

                  child: Icon(Icons.lightbulb, size: 30, color: Colors.blue,))),
          title: Text(text),
          subtitle: Text("Today"),
          trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios_rounded, color: Colors.blue,),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  
  Widget buildList(){
    return AnimatedList(
      key: globalKey,
      initialItemCount: tasks.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index, animation){
        return SlideTransition(
            position: Tween<Offset>(
              begin: const Offset(-1, 0),
              end: Offset(0, 0),
            ).animate(CurvedAnimation(
                parent: animation,
                curve: Curves.bounceIn,
                reverseCurve: Curves.bounceOut)),
            child: buildItem(tasks[index], index));
        }
        );
    
  }
  Widget buildscreen(){
    print("Screen is built");
    if(tasks.isEmpty){
      return Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
              child: Image.asset("assets/images/3327598.jpg"),
            ),
            Text("Add tasks and start beign producivity "),
            SizedBox(height: 100,)
          ],
        ),
      );
    }else{
      return buildList();
    }

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        actions: [
          ((){
            if(hour>6 && hour<18){
              return Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                    right: 20
                  ),
                  child: Icon(CustomIcons.cloud_sun, color: Colors.blue,size: 28,));
            } else {
              return Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                    right: 20
                  ),
                  child: Icon(CustomIcons.cloud_moon, color: Colors.blue,size: 28,));

            }

          }())
        ],
        leading: Container(
          width: 10,
          height: 10,
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 10,
            left: 10,
            right: 10,
            bottom: 10
          ),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.blue,
            borderRadius: BorderRadiusDirectional.circular(30)
          ),
          child: Center(child: Text("${tasks.length}")),
        ),
        title: Text("Todo App",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed:(){
          Navigator.of(context).push(
            new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context){
              return Scaffold(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                appBar: AppBar(

                  title: Text("Add a task"),
                ),
                body: TextField(
                  onSubmitted:(val){
                    addTask(val);
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();


                  },
                ),
              );
            })
          );
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      body: buildscreen()


      );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are not checking if your globalKey.currentState is null, before animating the introduction of a new item in an AnimatedList widget. Just add the following check before inserting into globalKey.currentState.insertItem(0).

```
if (globalKey.currentState != null)
```

This will make sure you wont insert the item while the widget is rebuilding and you will wait until the state is available. After adding this line your addTask() method should look like this :

```
  void addTask(String text) {
    print("Add task is built");
    setState(() {
      tasks.insert(0, text);
      if (globalKey.currentState != null) globalKey.currentState.insertItem(0);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you this solved my problem, but I need to understand more what was the problem if you can explain it to me I didn't get what you are trying to tell me

Comment: You need to wait for the item to rebuild before you can add to globalKey.currentState.

Comment: Okay I got it, I have another question if it is possible that also happened with my app, I tried to make a horizontal List view, and it works perfectly but the child of this list view takes all the height of the list view even when I placed shrink wrap true, and even when the container child it has a height value.

Comment: I will have to see the code. But I think if the container height is set then it should not expand to take all the available space. If the ListView does not work for you then you can try ScrollableRow. I request you to please like / up vote the accepted answer. Thanks

Comment: Thank you :) I will check your suggest